# Why can't phonon vacancy be used to trap ions?

Tags: circuit-construction, quantum-circuit, ion-trap-quantum-computing

Provided symmetric coulomb repulsion forces, I can't see why one could not dope an ion on a hetero structure that could confine the ion without interacting with either substrate-circuit or ionized atom or being close enough to cause tunneling. Is there any work being done on this?

Comment: You may have more luck with this on physics SE.

Comment: You want to confine ions using the random static potential generated by the doping? Not sure I understand the idea… in any case, what you're suggesting sounds a bit like qubits created in impurities like NV centers etc.